# Install Wine64 after compilation

Tags: 64-bit, wine

Hi guys I just compile Wine64 for Ubuntu 64 because I want to run 64bits windows applications on my 64bits ubuntu.

I did what it says in this guide http://wiki.winehq.org/Wine64 (Building a shared WoW64 setup paragraph) but now I dont know how to install it.

I want to know to which folder apply sudo make install.

So any idea? Thank you for all.

Answer (score 2):

From the instructions, it is clear that you have compiled wine in two different directories. One directory is ~/wine64 and the other one is ~/wine32. So, you will have to run `sudo make install` separately in both the directories.

In the Note part of "Building a shared WOW64 setup, it is clearly mentioned that:

> Make sure you always compile wine64 first to have the tools needed for
>   wine32, ***the order of installing them is nonrelevant***.

If you have the followed the instructions correctly, you will automatically have compiled wine64 before compiling wine32. It also indicates that both the directories need to be installed and the order in which you install them is irrelevant.